# Como superponer graficos con ggplot?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot

Tengo una tabla de 40 filas donde tengo valores repetidos, por ejemplo, USA se repite en 2 filas, Mexico igual, y asi.
Tengo datos repetidos porque quiero compararlos a traves del tiempo (USA 2020 - USA 2022, Mexico 2020, Mexico 2022,...). Para ello me gustaria hacer una grafica que tenga ambos datos de los paises pero en la misma barra donde se pueda ver una proporción para cada tabla por colores

Ejemplo:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c("USA", "Chile", "USA")
p <- c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3)
c <- data.frame(b, a, p)
```

Usando ggplot:

```
c %>% ggplot(aes(b, a, fill=p)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")
```

que me grafica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no quiero que sume las proporciones (1+3 en el caso de USA) y rellene los segmentos, sino que divida las proporciones y rellene los datos de USA de la fila x con un paleta de tonos azul y USA de la fila x+y con una paleta de tonos naranjas por ejemplo.

Practicamente me gustaria que se viera asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
all_data %>% ggplot(aes(Country.Name, Total.Cases, fill=Death_ratio)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(angle=45))
```

Pero con 2 paletas de colores por fila en la que aparece USA 1 y USA 2
La intuicion me diria que dividiera los datos en 2 data frames y luego aplicara:

```
ggplot()+geom_bar(datos de USA 1)+geom_bar(datos de USA 2)
```

Pero no creo que eso se pueda.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, tu ejemplo, por lo que dices, tiene un valor erróneo, o eso me parece: si la columna `a` hace las veces del año que mencionas más adelante, no es que tienes 3 años: `a <- c(1,2,3)` sino que USA tiene año 1 y 2 y chile solo 1, más bien algo así: `a <- c(1,1,2)`, esto es importante por que en realidad no tendrías en esta dimensión 3 categorías sino 2.

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- c(1,1,2)
b <- c("USA", "Chile", "USA")
p <- c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3)
c <- data.frame(b, a, p)

c %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=b, y=p, fill=factor(a))) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "orange")) +
    labs(fill=" a ")
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comentarios:

- Al ser valores numéricos, para asegurarnos que estos sean tratados como valores discretos como efectivamente sería un año, hay que usar `factor(a)`, al tener solo dos categorías para la estética `fill`, podemos configurar los colores mediante `scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "orange"))`